# How to remove/hide the recycling bin and All site content from the quick launch or remove the quick launch altogether?

Tags: quick-launch, recycle-bin

Ho can I remove the recycling bin and the 'All Site Content' link from the quick launch or remove the quick launch altogether

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps,

1. Navigate to the required page and Edit Page.
2. Add a Content Editor Web Part anywhere in the page.
3. Open tool pane of Content Editor Web Part by clicking “Modify Shared Web Part” option from top right drop down of web part.
4. Click on “Source Editor” button inside tool-pane and in “Text Entry” window paste the following lines.

   `<style>
       .ms-recyclebin {
       display:none;
       }
       </style>
       <style>
       .ms-quicklaunchheader{
       display:none;
       }
       </style>`
5. Click Save
6. Expand Layout section inside toolpane.
7. Check the Hidden checkbox and click OK.

Comment: This hides the whole quick launch, does anyone have a solution for the first part of the OP's question? I also just need to hide the Recycle Bin, not the entire Quick Launch.

Answer (score -1):

If it's for a whole site, you can set the master page to oslo.master (SharePoint 2013), which I believe doesn't show the quick launch.

You can also hide it through CSS, but I would not recommend hiding it on system pages, as the quick launch can be quite important in navigation some settings pages etc.

The CSS for hiding the quick launch is in any case the following

```
/** This stylesheet is used in sites where the quicklaunch is not needed **/
#s4-leftpanel {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
.s4-ca {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the above suggested steps, but that just didn't seem to work for SharePoint 2010 as the Content Editor Web Part doesn't seem to have a 'Source Editor' section SP 2010. After a lot of searching I found the below post to really work. If all else fails, please do try this one out.

http://www.splessons.com/hide-recycle-bin-and-all-site-content-links-in-quick-launch-of-sharepoint-using-css/#SPLessonPhoto[myGallery]/2/

Regards

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)